Are questions asking for 3rd party tools or resources on-topic here?
On Bricks SE, are questions whose goal is to find a 3rd party software or resource that fulfils a given task related to Lego bricks on-topic?
I am asking because:

Various other SE sites, in particular StackOverflow and related software development-related sites, strongly discourage this kind of questions, pointing instead to Software Recommendations SE.
I could not find any explicit mention in the Help Center for Bricks SE, nor on this Meta site.
And finally, such a question would undoubtedly be on-topic on the aforementioned Software Recommendations SE.

The issue with the last point I'm seeing is that I'd expect a suitable answer to be considerably more likely when posting such a question on Bricks SE (where many users actively use and know software related to Lego) than on Software Recommendations SE (where it takes a huge deal of luck for anyone with a deeper interest in Lego to come across the question at all).
I see several questions like what I'm thinking about on Bricks SE, e.g.:

Is there any software for designing and testing Technic mechanisms?
Identification tool for LEGO parts

but given the above factors, I'm looking for a definitive answer.
Also note that this is a different question than what was discussed in Are questions on 3rd party software on-topic?, which refers to questions about a particular (known) piece of software, for which users could be redirected to the software's own forum or support channels.

I think we're generally a little more accepting of "recommendations" type questions here on Bricks, and there are, as you've seen, already questions asking for recommendations for software for creating instructions, track layouts, and various robotics control systems.
That said, many of those don't necessarily have a definitive answer, but will often have a couple of recommendations with some fairly good description of the benefits and trade-offs of each.
